# SystemStackError (stack level too deep): error while uploading image in rails

Tags: iphone, ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am working on ROR and providing api to `IOS` app. In this app an `IOS` user uploads an image to Rails App. I am working with `paperclip` gem. This was working fine before I run the `bundle update` command. Now I am getting this error:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
 actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'activerecord-import', '>= 0.2.0'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

`IOS` developers are using `Base64` to encode an image before uploading to Rails App. My Rails app uses this method to decode the `photo_data`:

```
def decode_photo_data
    data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(self.photo_data))
    self.photo = data 
end
```

This was all working fine but I don’t know whether it is IOS bug or Rails bug. If it is Rails bug is it related to paperclip or something else. Please help.

Comment: will this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6636) help you to figure it out to solve ur problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution for this. I find out that this is a paperclip bug. Since I run the `bundle update` command, it downloaded a new paperclip version `paperclip-3.4.1` but before `bundle update` or `bundle install` it was using `paperclip-3.3.1` so now I updated my Gemfile to this:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.3.1'
```

And it starts working again in my case. No error now.